# Line Breaks in OpenPGP (Using PEAR with drupal)

Tags: php, drupal, pgp, openpgp

I am encrypting form submissions in drupal with Pear. The encryption//decryption is working fine, but line breaks are not working.

What I mean by that is, whether I use Enigma in thunderbird, or I use gpg4win, the message gets decrypted, but it looks like this:

Online Form = 1\r\nFirst Name: John\r\nLast Name: Smith\r\n

I have tried \n\n \r \r\n none of these seem to work.

So the question is how do I get line breaks to output properly after being decrypted.

(I'm using the drupal mail function sending plain text email with UTF-8 encoding, although I don't think this matters since the message is being decrypted)

Comment: Is the message like that before it gets encrypted?  Either way, you COULD just replace them:  `str_replace(array('\r', '\n'), array("\r", "\n"), $string);`...